# Get list from list values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with the following entries:

```
professions = {Peasant : ["Peasant", 10000], Merchant : ["Merchant", 15000], ...}
```

Where the keys are id's. Is there a clever way to get a list of the *first entries of the value lists*? I'd like a function that returns:

```
["Peasant", "Merchant", ...]
```

thanks for suggestions

Comment: Why can't you use the dict keys? Why are the keys repeated in the list values?

Comment: och, sorry, forgot to mention: the keys are id's

Comment: I think what @DanielRoseman is asking is what's the point of the first element in each list?  They are the same as the key, so why not just have `professions = {"Peasant": 10000, ...}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is quite under-specified, but presuming what you want to do is to extract the first value in each list, it would be:

```
names = [v[0] for v in professions.values()]
```

Comment: Jup, that's what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @anhoppe the more concrete way to say that is to accept the answer :)

Comment: ;-) will do, but have to wait 10min

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for :

```
[value[0] for value in professions.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .values() method

```
professions.values()
```

Comment: Without having it tried: wouldn't .values() just return the lists [["Peasant", 1000], ["Merchant", 15000]] ?

Comment: yes, you would have to loop through and get list[x][0] where list is the returned list, and x is each list index.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to retrieve all keys of the dict: `professions.keys()`

Example:

```
professions = {Peasant : ["Peasant", 10000], Merchant : ["Merchant", 15000]}

print(professions.keys()) #["Peasant", "Merchant"]
```